# Java servlets vs Java class in webapp

Tags: java, class, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I am quite new to Java/Servlets/Tomcat etc. but have a fairly good understanding of web apps from my days as a CGI/PHP developer.

I have a JSP **index.jsp** that presents a table from a database.

I have a **Results.class** that is a normal Java class (not a servlet) that queries a database and returns a string from a method: **`public static String displayAllResults()`**

The String being returned is an html table. 
So in my **index.jsp** there is a line that says something like:

**`String table = Result.displayAllResults();`**

And then the table is displayed as I'd hoped - All good!

My question is this: is there any advantage/disadvantage to using normal Java classes instead of Java servlets in this manner or should I port all of my classes to servlets for added functionality??

Comment: This isn't how you should be doing things at all really. This is a very naive and non-scaleable approach to development. You obviously can use Java classes as PHP scripts but this isn't what Java was designed for. Further, a JSP _is a_ servlet.

Comment: Writing Java in JSP is almost always bad. Writing HTML in Java is almost always bad. Separate functionality.

Comment: If you are learning JSP, you should start with JSF instead. You will enjoy more easily MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using MVC frameworks like Spring MVC or struts2. You should always have clear abstractions:

- Dao Layer
- Service Layer
- Business Layer
- Model Objects
- DTO's
- Helpers/Utils

Whenever possible use EL languages like JSTL/OGNL on JSP pages. Never ever use scriptlets. If you use any of the above MVC frameworks, you'd probably never need to use Servlets directly!

Displaying grids with data from database use something like DisplayTag or Jqgrid (with Ajax calls)

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your answers. My next question was actually going to be about the advantages of using JSTL which is something I am going to be looking at doing I think.

Comment: @thonnor - Please accept and/or upvote any of the answer, if you feel they really helped you. Like that people will be encouraged to help you in the future.

Comment: I've tried up-voting several of the answers but I need a reputation of 15 or higher to do this. I only joined the site this morning and so far have zero reputation :(

Comment: @thonnor - Don't worry you'll soon get those reputations. Btw thanks for accepting my answer. Happy hacking ;)

Comment: So a day later and I have got myself a quick tutorial on JSTL and have created a page that performs and presents my DB query in a FRACTION of the code I that wrote in my original class. 

Thanks for all the help and guidance folks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's generally considered poor practice to be invoking Java from a scriptlet in a JSP page. JSP is intended to do HTML formatting, with some extra intelligence around using the `Locale` and things like that. A better PHP, if you will. Database processing should be handled by a servlet.

Comment: Database processing should be handled by a service, and the data exposed to JSP via a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I think understanding the purpose of `Servlet`, `JSP`, and `normal classes` will answer your question.

As per my understanding, `JSP` is used for View purpose, that is, rendering UI to the screen is role of jsp.

whereas, `Servlets` are used as a controller, whose role is to act as a bridge between your Views and Models.

`Normal java classes` can act as a Model, here you can perform some core business logic.